# qt_gui_cpp failed Rapsberry PI 4

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to install ROS Kinetic on my Raspberry PI4 using Raspbian Buster:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

But following the instruction here => https://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi
When I type this line => sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic

I got this output:

> ==> Processing catkin package: 'qt_gui_cpp'
> ==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh' Makefile
> exists, skipping explicit cmake
> invocation...
> ==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
> ==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
> [ 83%] Built target qt_gui_cpp [ 88%]
> Compiling generated code for
> qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...
> make[3]: warning: jobserver
> unavailable: using -j1. Add '+' to
> parent make rule. /usr/bin/ld: cannot
> find
> -lcatkin::rosconsole::wrapped-linker-option0
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find
> -lcatkin::rostime::wrapped-linker-option0
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
> status make[3]: * [Makefile:38:
> "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/qt_gui_cpp/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui_cpp/libqt_gui_cpp_sip".so]
> Error 1 make[2]:
> *[src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/build.make:61:
> /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/qt_gui_cpp/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui_cpp/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.so]
> Error 2 make[1]: *
> [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:566:
> src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all]
> Error 2 make: * [Makefile:141: all]
> Error 2 <== Failed to process package
> 'qt_gui_cpp': Command
> '['/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh', 'make',
> '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit
> status 2
>
> Reproduce this error by running:
> ==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp
> && /opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh make -j4
> -l4
>
> Command failed, exiting.

Because I didn't find anything that can solve my issue, I would be glad if I can have any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341070/qt_gui_cpp-failed-rapsberry-pi-4/) by [MCmobil](https://answers.ros.org/users/50706/mcmobil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-01-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found the error, the rqt_gui_cpp doesn't compile so I changed it completely and clone the one existing on git by doing this:

cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src

sudo rm -rf python_qt_binding

git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization

Maybe the one previously downloaded is obsolete...? anyway it has solved this part!

---

Originally posted by [MCmobil](https://answers.ros.org/users/50706/mcmobil/) with karma: 33 on 2020-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marnett5](https://answers.ros.org/users/51998/marnett5/) on 2020-02-25**:
This did work, though unfortunately I have another issue with the OGRE package not being found, with a different version of Libboost needed for the installation. I'm stuck here at the moment if you want to help out.

**Comment by [MCmobil](https://answers.ros.org/users/50706/mcmobil/) on 2020-02-25**:
Hi Marnett5,
Yes I will try! It has been a while I haven't touched it, for now I don't have access to the Raspberry but I may have it back soon.
Anyway would you provide me the steps you have done? It will help me to remind and understand where it is blocking.
Thanks!

**Comment by [espenseventyr](https://answers.ros.org/users/52102/espenseventyr/) on 2020-02-26**:
Yes that worked for me too, thanks (git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding). There is an issue with libboost mentioned on http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi under section 3.3. Did you see that? I'm compiling now but seems like this will work for the desktop install. For the desktop_full the conflict seems unresolvable, I'll add packages as I need them beyond the desktop install.

**Comment by [MCmobil](https://answers.ros.org/users/50706/mcmobil/) on 2020-02-26**:
Yes I could remember it. I haven't faced that issue because I took only a light version of ROS (I wanted to use something light but efficient). Maybe the desktop_full version assuming using some libraries that are not obviously used by the Pi?

**Comment by [Marnett5](https://answers.ros.org/users/51998/marnett5/) on 2020-02-27**:
I had some issues with OGRE when installing the desktop version, but had no problem installing the light version. However, I gave up when trying to install turtlebot 2 packages; too many brick walls with that thing.

**Comment by [MCmobil](https://answers.ros.org/users/50706/mcmobil/) on 2020-02-28**:
Hmmm I would advise to start a new thread. You can make reference to this post, but I think it will be easier and cleaner to not do it here. Open it and I will help you there!